# angularjs 1.5 service not triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, getter-setter, route-provider

I have a form in view1, with multiple input fields. Button submit successfully posts data (stores in db), however the controller (ListController) does not seem to call a service's getter successfully.

In view2, nothing is displayed when calling `job` or 'summaryService.job' - not even "undefined" as initially declared in the service.

I'm using a routeProvider function in app.js - does this maybe interfere with calling services and controllers? The rest of the controllers work fine - just not the communication between the controllers and the services.
Or is ng-click not a good way to trigger the setter service?

view1:

```
<form name="campaignForm1" action="#/setup-step2" ng-submit="setJobtitle(campaign.jobtitle); submitForm(campaign);">
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Job title: </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="jobtitle" ng-model="campaign.jobtitle"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>ID: </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="id" ng-model="campaign.vacancyid"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<button ng-click="setJobtitle(campaign.jobtitle); submitForm(campaign)" > Proceed </button>
```

controller view 1:

```
ctr.controller('Step1Controller',
    ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', '$location', 'summaryService' function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $location, summaryService)
                {
                    $scope.setJobtitle = function(jobtitle) {
                        summaryService.setJobtitle(jobtitle);
                    };
    ]);
```

service summaryService:

```
app.service('summaryService', function() {

this.job = "undefined";  
return {
    getJobtitle: function() {
       return this.job;
   },
   setJobtitle: function(value) {
       this.job = value
   }
};
});
```

View 2 does not show anything, no matter whether i call `{{job}}` or `{{summaryService.getJobtitle()}}`.

Controller view 2:

```
ctr.controller('ListController',
    ['$scope', 'Test', 'summaryService', function ($scope, Test, summaryService)
                    { 
                        $scope.job = summaryService.getJobtitle();
}]);
```

I suspect that there is something wrong with passing and calling values from within the controllers?

Git link https://github.com/2dorian/cmx

Comment: try switching from service to factory . if not working consult this syntax http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html

Comment: i used a factory before and applied var instead of this - but that did not do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `this` inside getJobtitle referret to returned object so to fix this problem you could:

1.

```
app.service('summaryService', function() {
this.job = "undefined";  
this.getJobtitle = function() {
       return this.job;
};
this.setJobtitle = function(value) {
       this.job = value
 };
});
```

or

2.

```
app.service('summaryService', function() {
return {
  job: "undefined",  
  getJobtitle: function() {
       return this.job;
  },
  setJobtitle: function(value) {
       this.job = value
  }
};
});
```

Worked example on codepen - http://codepen.io/maksimr/pen/oYmjmB

Comment: (getter works) view2 successfully returns the initial value 'undefined' using your suggestion - awesome! now the setter

Comment: is not changing the job value?

Comment: @YaeVo setter also should work, you should call setter as `summaryService.setJobtitle('foo')` or bind `setJobtitle` to `summaryService` like this `var setJobtitle = summaryService.setJobtitle.bind(summaryService)`

Comment: @YaeVo I have added link on worked example on codepen

Comment: ok, so this works BUT not for view2. i changed the code as you suggested, and on view1, the value of {{job}} successfully changes after submit - so the setter is functioning. As soon as I go to view2, the initial value 'undefined' is shown again - so the getter gets the old value.

Comment: @YaeVo you could look at my example on code pen, you should use `summaryService.getJobtitle()` in your template or you should always update scope variable job($scope.job) when update `job` because in your example  $scope.job refer to primitive value which is immutable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130898/discussion-between-yaevo-and-maksimr).